# THREE.js rotating camera around an object using orbit path

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js, geometry

I am struggling in solving this problem.

On my scene, I have a camera which looks at the center of mass of an object. I have a some buttons that enable to set camera position on particular view (front view, back view,...) along a invisible sphere that surroung the object (constant radius).

When I click on the button, i would like the camera to move from its start position to the end position along the sphere surface. When camera moves I would like it to keep fixing center of mass of the object.

Has anyone have a clue on how to achieve this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy/prefer to use basic trigonometry then in your initialisation section you could do this:

```
var cameraAngle = 0;
var orbitRange = 100;
var orbitSpeed = 2 * Math.PI/180;
var desiredAngle = 90 * Math.PI/180;
...
camera.position.set(orbitRange,0,0);
camera.lookAt(myObject.position);
```

Then in your render/animate section you could do this:

```
if (cameraAngle == desiredAngle) { orbitSpeed = 0; }
else {
  cameraAngle += orbitSpeed;
  camera.position.x = Math.cos(cameraAngle) * orbitRange;
  camera.position.y = Math.sin(cameraAngle) * orbitRange;
}
```

Of course, your buttons would modify what the `desiredAngle` was (0°, 90°, 180° or 270° presumably), you need to rotate around the correct plane (I am rotating around the XY plane above), and you can play with the `orbitRange` and `orbitSpeed` until you hare happy.

You can also modify `orbitSpeed` as it moves along the orbit path, speeding up and slowing down at various `cameraAngle`s for a smoother ride.  This process is called 'tweening' and you could search on 'tween' or 'tweening'  if you want to know more.  I think Three.js has tweening support but have never looked into it.

Oh, also remember to set your camera's `far` property to be greater than `orbitRadius` or you will only see the front half of your object and, depending on what it is, that might look weird.

Comment: how do  u set .position.z to go all the way around??